# Case class .copy with upperbound value

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having problems using the `.copy` method of a case class which has an upper bound value. The example is something like this:

```
sealed abstract class SomeOtherClass[A <: SomethingElse]{...}

final case class SomeClass[LI <: SomeOtherClass[_]](
    value1: String,
    value2: LI)
```

And in another part of my code I have:

```
val instance: SomeClass(_) = service.getInstance()
...
instance.copy(value1 = "Something new")
```

But when I try to rung my code I get an error saying something along the lines:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[_$2]
[error]  required: List[LI]
```

The question is, is there a way to use the `.copy` method for something like this? Or what would be the recommended way to do so?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this... what version of Scala?

Comment: @LeviRamsey 2.12.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try bounding the existential type like so

```
val instance: SomeClass[_ <: SomeOtherClass[_]] = service.getInstance()
```

corresponding to `LI <: SomeOtherClass[_]`. For example,

```
trait Animal
case class Cat() extends Animal
case class Dog() extends Animal

sealed abstract class House[A <: Animal](a: A)
case class DogHouse(dog: Dog) extends House(dog)
case class CatHouse(cat: Cat) extends House(cat)

final case class SomeClass[LI <: House[_]](value1: String, value2: LI)

val instance: SomeClass[_ <: House[_]] = SomeClass("Floppy", DogHouse(Dog()))
instance.copy(value1 = "Something new") // res0: SomeClass[_$2] = SomeClass(Something new,DogHouse(Dog()))
```

Comment: Strange that the boundry is needed. It should be implied by the definition of case class SomeClass though?